# How to replace except tags and pushes in gitlab-ci.yml file with rules?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a ci-cd pipeline where I am using the following except condition currently:

```
except:
    - tags
    - pushes
```

With the increasing conditions, now I have to use `rules`. I cannot use `only` and `except` with rules now. Can someone help me with this?

I have tried the following snippet:

```
rules:
      - if: 'tags && pushes'
        when: never
```

But this gives the following error:

```
jobs:build_info:rules:rule if invalid expression syntax
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use predefined environment variables:

```
rules:
 - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" || $CI_COMMIT_TAG != null'
   when: never
```

Comment: Worked, just need to use quotes around the values i.e "push" and "null".  Link for reference: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#run-jobs-for-scheduled-pipelines

Comment: Oh, good point! I'll update the answer. However, I don't think it applies to `null` since I believe that's the type `null` and not a string. Correct me if I'm wrong and I'll update that part as well. They don't quote it here: [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#check-if-a-variable-is-undefined)

Comment: shouldn't there be a logical OR here? https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#combine-multiple-keywords-with-only-or-except

Comment: @SergeyBulavkin yes, i believe you're correct, i updated the answer